# Can I have Component interfaces in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Say I have a `<Modal>` that takes a `<Header>` `<Content>` and `<Footer>`.

```js
(
  <Modal>
    <Header>Foo</Header>
    <Content>Foo</Content>
    <Footer>Foo</Footer>
  </Modal>
)
```

Now, inside my `Modal` component I'll probably have code like the following:

```js
const header = children.find(child => child.type === Header)
```

In order to get a reference to the rendered header.

Now, what if from the consumer of the modal, I needed a decorated `Header`. Let's just call it `DecoratedHeader`

```js
// DecoratedHeader
const DecoratedHeader = () => <Header>Foo <Icon type="lock" /></Header>

// consumer
(
  <Modal>
    <DecoratedHeader />
    <Content>Foo</Content>
    <Footer>Foo</Footer>
  </Modal>
)
```

The line above wouldn't work anymore, as `DecoratedHeader` type is **not** `Header`. However, it IS rendering a `Header`.

It feels like there's the concept of "interface" which is missing. Ultimately, the `Modal` cares for a `Header` to be rendered, but if you wrap it under a "custom" component there's no way for it to know that it is still a `Header`.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

To expand more about my use cases, I don't need an alternative solution. I need to know whether React has support for a mechanism equivalent to an interface, where 2 different Components that comply with the Liskov Substitution Principle (meaning they're swappable) can have a way to be picked by the parent.

Specifically, replacing this "hardcoded implementation" search, with an "interface" search:

```
-const specificChild = children.find(child => child.type === SomeComponent)
+const componentInterface = children.find(child => ????)

 // Get a prop out of that component interface
 const { someInterfaceProp } = componentInterface.props;

 return (
   <div>
     {componentInterface}  {/* render it on a specific place */}
   </div>
 )
```

Comment: Good question. I think this could be done by passing header type ref to DecoratedHeader

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle
I am not sure. Will try by my self

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the only thing you're going to be doing with these components is rendering them in specific spots of the modal, i would do them as separate props. For example:

```
const Modal = ({ header, content, footer }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {header}
      <SomethingElseAllModalsHave />
      {content}
      {footer}
    </div>
  )
}

// ... used like:
const Example = () => {
  return (
    <Modal
      header={<DecoratedHeader />}
      content={<Content>Foo</Content>}
      footer={<Footer>Foo</Footer>}
    />
  )
}
```

If you need the modal to not just render the other components, but give them some information too, you could use a [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html). Basically the same as my example above, but now you pass in functions instead of elements

```
const Modal = ({ header, content, footer }) => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {header(isVisible)}
      <SomethingElseAllModalsHave />
      {content(isVisible)}
      {footer(isVisible}
    </div>
  )
}

// ... used like:
const Example = () => {
  return (
    <Modal
      header={() => <DecoratedHeader />}
      content={(isVisible) => <Content>{isVisible ? "Foo" : "Bar"</Content>}
      footer={(isVisible) => isVisible ? <Footer>Foo</Footer> : null}
    />
  )
}
```

EDIT:

When you write the JSX `<DecoratedHeader/>`, the object that is produced contains no information about `<Header>`. It's basically just an object with a type (ie, a reference to `DecoratedHeader`) and some props (none in this case). Header only enters the picture when DecoratedHeader is rendered, which won't be until *after* Modal is rendered.

So whatever the characteristics are that Modal will use to identify what is and is not a header, it needs to be something that is on DecoratedHeader, not just on Header. Perhaps you could add a static property to any component that counts as a header, and then check for that:

```
const Header = () => {
  // Whatever the code is for this component.
}

Header.isHeader = true;

const DecoratedHeader = () => <Header>Foo <Icon type="lock" /></Header>

DecoratedHeader.isHeader = true;
```

Then you'll look for it something like this (you should use [React.Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren), because `children` is not guaranteed to be an array):

```
const header = React.Children.toArray(children).find(child => child.type.isHeader);
```

Comment: What if you wanted the consumer to pass specifically a `Header`, so that they cannot pass something like an `Accordion`?

Comment: I see were you're going with your alternate solutions. However, I have many use cases for which I need an answer to the question instead of other approaches. Essentially, the  `child.type === Component` check

Comment: I've edited in some more ideas. But inspecting the types and props of children and then acting on those is not something i recommend doing unless you absolutely need to. React's design makes it easy for a parent to tell a child what to render, but the reverse is tricky.

Comment: Based from this information, I'll conclude that the pattern itself of using `type === Component` is fundamentally flawed. Thanks for your answer Nicholas!